# WD My Book (10EAVS) doesn't show files

Tags: windows, drivers, external-hard-drive

I have an external data device with many important files on it (about 500 GB). When I try to show the files on my PC, it shows that the capacity is actually taken (500GB), but I see no files in it. Happily, if I connect the device by USB to my TV screen, it shows all the directories and files. I've been thoroughly searching for help online. Perhaps I need to download a driver? Perhaps there are some encoding problems (FAT/whatever I don't really know a thing about it).

How can I access my files on my drive?

Answer (score 0):

They might be hidden. Depending on the edition of Windows you have, there is a different procedure for showing hidden files, but you can access all of them from a My Computer or Windows Explorer window. Look for a place to change the Folder Options and select the "Show Hidden Files and Folders" setting.
Also, try running a disk scan on it, in case there is a file system corruption. NTFS will crap out from time to time (FAT/FAT32 is much worse) and a CHKDSK needs to be run on it (Right click on drive, click Properties, and find the check disk for errors button and CLICK IT.)

Comment: i've changed dir properties to show hidden files&folders, but it shows none. also after disc scan there are no particular damage/error... is there some other option? i really appreciate your help!